# Selecting the first record from a collection with Duplicate column values C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list of Records.

```
public class Record 
{
 public int Id{get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Description{get;set;}
}

List<Record> records = 
{
  1, "A","Desc1",
  2, "A","Desc2",
  3, "B","Desc3",
  4, "B","Desc4",
  5, "C","Desc5"
}
```

I need to check the Name and if its same , pick the first record . So , I need the output as :

```
 List<Record> records = 
    {
      1, "A","Desc1",
      3, "B","Desc3",
      5, "C","Desc5"
    }
```

I tried to group , but I dont need all the columns in grouping list.

Comment: is there anything that makes your question [C#-3.0] and [C#-4.0] specific? These are outdated versions from more than a decade ago.

Answer (score 1):

you can use Linq with a group by name and take the first group element:

```cs
var cleaned = from r in records
              group r by r.Name into grp
              select grp.First();
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want a complete list, and not just a single item.

I would suggest to use a `HashSet` which does not allow any duplicates.  And if it is a duplicate or not, you need to control through overriding the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` functions in the class like this:

```
public class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Record other = obj as Record;

        return !Object.ReferenceEquals(null, other)
            && String.Equals(this.Name, other.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 13;
        hash = (hash * 7) + this.Name.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

The `Equals` and `GetHashCode` functions MUST only work based on the `Name` (because this is determining your uniqueness in this case).

Then you can simply create a `Hashset` from your list

```
HashSet<Record> uniqueRecords = new HashSet<Record>(records);
```

If you really need a list, then you can just convert back to a list.

Comment: Why do you use `int hash = 13; hash = (hash * 7) + ` fragment? why not `return Name?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;` your current code actually returns `91 + Name.GetHashCode();`

Comment: Shorter version for `Equals`: `public override bool Equals(object obj) => obj is Record other && string.Equals(Name, other?.Name);`

Answer (score 0):

One attempt could be to sort the list of records by description and after that filter by distinct names:

```
var filteredRecords = records.OrderBy(x => x.Description).DistinctBy(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: Maybe you missed to warn that this method applies only to .NET 6...